# I can not move icons in Unity Launcher.

Tags: unity-2d

My Launcher was very smooth.But yesterday onwards Launcher become darker and not smooth.I can't move the icons as to rearrange it's position.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can reset your unity, to reset unity, 1st : make sure you have "dconf" you can check this on dash, if you don't have, you can install dconf from software center. then you go to the terminal insert this

> dconf reset -f /org/compiz/

then log out and back, 2nd : insert this on terminal

> unity --reset-icons

log out and back

hope this will solve your problem